# Minimizing expected loss based on asymmetric losses

Tags: probability

I came across this problem in a book and am not sure how to approachi it:

A dart will hit the random point $Y$ in $(0,1)$ according to the density 
$f_{Y} (t) = 2t$.

You must guess the value of $Y$ . (Your guess is a constant, not random.) You will lose \$2 per unit error if $Y$ is to the left of your guess, and will lose \$1 per unit error on the right. Find best guess in terms of expected loss.

Comment: First calculate the expected value and the error (I guess you mean the standard deviation). Then write a formual for the average money lost as a function of your chosen value $X$ and minimise it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build expected loss function. It argument is your guess, say x. And it value is integral of you loss or profit for each outcome multiplied by outcome probability.

For example, you guess is x and outcome is t. Then you lose 2*(x-t) with probability 2t if t < x and win t-x with same probability if t > x.

Actually this integral is trivial and easily calculated. Then you have to find extremum of you function and this will be your best guess.